# deconstruct JSON object in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to deconstruct this object to get "Swiss franc", assuming i don't know the key CHF.

```
currencies = {CHF: {name: "Swiss franc", symbol: "Fr."}}
```

My attempts:

```
Object.values(Object.values(currencies)[0] 
// -> Swiss franc,Fr.

Object.values(Object.values(currencies)[0].name
// -> S,w,i,s,s, ,f,r,a,n,c
  // why does it split the string?? not retrieve the value based on key name?? 
    // i know how to join the strings back, but i'm confused why is this result?)
```

Comment: `Object.values(Object.values(currencies)[0].name` -> `Object.values(currencies)[0].name`. Why the double `Object.values`?

Comment: @somniumm please spare some time to check the answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

just a little modification to your code:

```js
const currencies = {CHF: {name: "Swiss franc", symbol: "Fr."}}

console.log(Object.values(Object.values(currencies)[0])[0])

// OR Simply 

console.log(Object.values(currencies)[0].name)
```

Comment: thanks, but why doesn't the second method work? i meant with .name

Comment: The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, so when you do it for the `name` key it will split the value for that key in an array

Answer (score 1):

#### `Object.entries` Implementation [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

**Explanation**

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs. This is the same
> as iterating with a for...in loop, except that a for...in loop
> enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.

**Working Example**

```js
const currencies = { CHF: { name: "Swiss franc", symbol: "Fr.", }}
console.log(Object.entries(currencies)[0][1].name);
```

**Code Explanation**

```
Object.entries(currencies)
```

The above statement return an array as below

```
[["CHF", {symbol: 'Fr.', name: 'Swiss franc'}]]
```

An array of combination of key value pairs in the object.

We are interested in the node zero of the array and index one of the first node of array.

So it will be

```
Object.entries(currencies)[0][1].name
```

#### `Object.values` implementation. [Reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

**Explanation**

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a
> for...in loop. (The only difference is that a for...in loop enumerates
> properties in the prototype chain as well.)

**Working Example**

```js
const currencies = { CHF: { name: "Swiss franc", symbol: "Fr.", }}
console.log(Object.values(currencies)[0].name);
```

**Code Explanation**

```
Object.values(currencies)
```

Tie above expression will return the array of values. Since we have only one key, the output of above statement will be

```
[{ symbol: 'Fr.', name: 'Swiss franc' }]
```

So the requird node will be

```
Object.values(currencies)[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

`currencies = {CHF: {name: "Swiss franc", symbol: "Fr."}}`

***This will do it,***
`Object.values(currencies)[0].name`

Breakdown :-

`Object.values(currencies)` gives `[{name: "Swiss franc", symbol: "Fr."}]`

`Object.values(currencies)[0]` gives `{name: "Swiss franc", symbol: "Fr."}`

`Object.values(currencies)[0].name` gives **Swiss franc**.